# How to supress results set in Sybase?

Tags: sap-ase

I Have to suppress result set from a stored proc Is there any set command to suppress the result set in sybase stored proc?

I have a stored proc,i want to use that in my front end and script with out duplicating

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fmtonly option.

set fmtonly on

go

exec stored_proc(...)

go

Comment: There is also "set noexec on".